# Try/Catch and loop

Tags: c#

1)After try and catch i want to loop it again to give new number("Console.ReadLine("Give correct number"))because user does not entered string convertable to double
2Second problem is, when user give wrong number i would like to loop again to enter new number. This version of program give message to small or to big number and exit

corrected

```
double number=10,11;
Console.WriteLine("Give a number");
string w=Console.ReadLine();
try
{
double d = Convert.ToDouble(w);
}
catch(FormatException)
{
Console.WriteLine("it is not a number");        
}
double dd=Convert.ToDouble(w);
if (dd == number)
{
Console.WriteLine("Yes, it is!");
}
else if (number<dd)
{
Console.WriteLine("to big number");
}
else if(number>dd)
{
Console.WriteLine("to small number");
}
Console.ReadLine();
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Try this one:

```
var number =3;
do{
    Console.WriteLine("Give a number");
    string w=Console.ReadLine();
    try
    {
        double d = Convert.ToDouble(w);
    }
    catch(FormatException)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("it is not a number");
        continue; // not a number starting new iteration of the loop
    }
    double dd=Convert.ToDouble(w);
    if (dd == number)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Yes, it is!");
        break; // The number guessed exiting loop
    }
    else if (dd>number)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("to big number");
    }
    else if(dd<number)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("to small number");
    }
}
while (true);
Console.ReadLine();
```

Comment: Never ever use `while (true)` it is evil!

Comment: @PatrickHofman even in this example? If it allow you to provide more compact code that is less error prone it can be used.

Comment: Yes. Learning fresh developers such anti-patterns is just bad.

Comment: @PatrickHofman It is very controversial. KISS principle says not over complicate the solution. So do not see a reason why you are "banning" usage of `while(true)`

Comment: I guess you never had to debug a running production server which had a 100% CPU load because some unexpected condition kept it running forever...

Comment: @PatrickHofman, if I never set `valid=true` in your case it would run forever as well. So it doesn't seem that `while(true)` is a root cause.

Answer (score 3):

First, use a `do..while(condition)` to keep asking until the user enters a valid number. Second, use `TryParse` to check if the value is valid. This is better than exception handling and converting it twice. Not sure why you are using `double`s, but `int`s might be more appropriate.

```
bool valid = false;
do
{
    bool newValidState;
    Console.WriteLine("Give a number");

    string w = Console.ReadLine();

    double d;
    if (!double.TryParse(w, out d))
    {
        Console.WriteLine("it is not a number");
        newValidState = false;
    }
    else if (d == number)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Yes, it is!");
        newValidState = true;
    }
    else if (wyliczona < wybor) // these conditions seem unrelated to `d`
                                // are they okay?
    {
        Console.WriteLine("to big number");
        newValidState = false;
    }
    else if(wyliczona > wybor)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("to small number");
        newValidState = false;
    }
    else
    {
        Console.WriteLine("unknown condition. needs work.");
        newValidState = false;
    }

    valid = newValidState;
}
while (!valid);
```

Note the use of `newValidState`, which will make sure you always assign a new value to `valid`. This helps to prevent endless loops due to never setting a value. The code will not compile unless every branch sets `newValidState` to a value.

Comment: If OP must use `double`, it may help to point out that the `==` may fail under certain conditions without an epsilon test

Comment: Yes, very easy to mess things up @pinkfloydx33.